# PHP - memcached copy key/value from one server to another

Tags: php, memcached

I am curious is there a possibility in PHP to copy key/value from one memcached server directly to another using Memcached module?
Is connections to 2 different servers at one time allowed at all?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The following would allow you to connect to two different Memcached servers and set the same data on both:

```
//Server A
$memcacheA = new Memcache;
$memcacheA->connect(216.239.51.99, 11211) or die ("Could not connect");

//Server B
$memcacheB = new Memcache;
$memcacheB->connect(115.239.51.98, 11211) or die ("Could not connect");

//Getting data from your database.
$myVal = $customObj->getSomethingFromDB();

//If data not stored on Server A
if($memcacheA->get('var_key') === false){
    //Store it on Server A
    $memcacheA->set('var_key', $myVar, MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED, 50);
}

//If data not stored on Server B
if($memcacheB->get('var_key') === false){
    //Store it on Server B
    $memcacheB->set('var_key', $myVar, MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED, 50);
}
```

Depending on your use case, this may or may not be a good solution. Depends on what your situation is and what you're attempting to achieve.